# Scrapy error "No module named cmdline"

Tags: python, scrapy

I've some problem with Scrapy on my mac, I checked many website to find an answer but I didn't find any good one.

Here's my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "scrapy-ctl.py", line 6, in <module>
      from scrapy.command.cmdline import execute
ImportError: No module named cmdline
```

I actually have Scrapy 0.16.3 ,Twisted 12.3.0, lxml 3.1beta1, libxml2 and libxslt

Thank you for your time !

Comment: What happens if from the Python interpreter you just run `import scrapy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took a while to work out and involved searching the [scrapy github repository](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy), but the [cmdline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/d788ba8a44e0538188872977a8705c1209a09194/scrapy/cmdline.py) module has moved. Instead of your current import, try this:

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
```

Comment: *blushes* I'm just happy to help. :)